# Hiding the Windows 7 notification area

Tags: c#, windows, api

Our IT team has, very annoyingly, set a group policy to show all the notification icons. Apparently some of our staff couldn't find the printer icon. I am currently looking at 18 icons.

My question is, preferably using c#, can I force Windows to return the notification area to its usual behaviour?

Comment: I don't understand the preference for C#. Why do you care what language is used? I also don't see that this is a programming issue. You don't want to write a program, you just want to fix your own machine's settings. That's a superuser question surely. The people to talk to are your IT people.

Comment: LOL Awesomeness... Go IT guys!

Comment: Have you tried to turn it off and on again?

Comment: But on a more serious note: This might be better suited for superusers.com, even if the solution involves some scripting or coding. Also have you tried disabling icons you don't need or do you need them in general, just don't want to have them visible all the time and/or can't disable them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd just email IT dep. asking to be excluded from this particular GPO. No need for coding here.

[This link](http://www.grouppolicy.biz/2010/05/how-to-exclude-individual-users-or-computers-from-a-group-policy-object/) looks like something you can forward to IT dep. for future reference, explaining how to accomplish this particular task.

**edit**

If you are a local Administrator on your computer, you might also try to follow what's being suggested in [this SuperUser question](https://serverfault.com/questions/65011/how-can-i-override-group-policy-using-a-local-administrator-account) about overriding a GPO.

Comment: Yeah I've tried that. We have cover all policies, I'll suggest it but I'm looking for this answer as a last resort.

Comment: Added another maybe useful resource for hints.